# How to handle checked in input type='checkbox' in React?

Tags: javascript, html, reactjs

I have a group of checkboxes, some of them are pre-checked and some will be updated from the user. problem is the checkboxes render fine in initial render but they don't change on click. The value of 'checked' gets updated on change (onChange)

```
<input
   type = 'checkbox'
   style = {{margin : '0'}}
   checked = {this.state[elem]}
   value = {elem}
   onChange = {this.checked}
 /> {elem}
```

and in the checked method

```
checked = e => {
    this.setState({
        [e.target.value] : !this.state[e.target.value]
    })
}
```

Comment: Hi shahriar, please take a look at my solution below and let me know if that helps :)

Answer (score 3):

You haven't shared with us how you are generating these inputs, but the primary issue has to do with using a single source of truth for all your inputs. You want to give each input, particularly the object that corresponds to that input, their own checked-state.

Considering the following example with working codesandbox: https://codesandbox.io/s/relaxed-feynman-1thb8

```
import React from "react";
import ReactDOM from "react-dom";

import "./styles.css";

const arr = [
  { val: "Cat", checked: false },
  { val: "Dog", checked: true },
  { val: "Turtle", checked: false }
];

class App extends React.Component {
  state = {
    arr: arr
  };

  handleCheck = e => {
    const arrCopy = [...this.state.arr];
    const itemToUpdate = arrCopy.find(item => item.val === e.target.value);

    itemToUpdate.checked = !itemToUpdate.checked;

    this.setState({
      arr: arrCopy
    });
  };

  createInputs = () => {
    const { arr } = this.state;

    return arr.map(elem => {
      return (
        <div>
          <input
            type="checkbox"
            style={{ margin: "0" }}
            checked={elem.checked}
            value={elem.val}
            onChange={this.handleCheck}
          />
          {elem.val}
        </div>
      );
    });
  };

  render() {
    return <div>{this.createInputs()}</div>;
  }
}

const rootElement = document.getElementById("root");
ReactDOM.render(<App />, rootElement);
```

In the above code, we organize your state-data as in array of objects, making it easier for you to render the mark-up AND keep track of the checked state of each input. Then in the handleCheck function, we identify the checked item, find its corresponding object in the array and toggle the checked state of that item.

Comment: Hi, 

Thanks for the help but the problem stays. I can change the checked value and if I console.log inside checked={console.log(this.state.checked)}, it changes but the view doesn't change

Comment: Can you take a look at the sandbox and let me know what parts of the code you have used?

Comment: Solved now, I was ran into an async trap. Thanks a lot.

Comment: You're welcome! I wasnt sure what might be wrong since we didn't see that in your post :) @shahriarhasan please consider upvoting and marking this as the solution friend.

Answer (score 0):

Set input's `name` property to property equivalent to that of state's key. Also your way of accessing object's key as `this.state[elem]` is inappropriate as `elem` is not a variable(that should contain string as state's key).

I have prepared codesandbox for use case. Here is codesandbox link for the example : https://codesandbox.io/embed/clever-colden-2ydb6

Updated code:

```
checked = e => {
  const checked = e.target.checked;
  const name = e.target.name;
  this.setState({
    [name]: checked
  });
};

render() {
  return (
    <div>
      <input
        type="checkbox"
        style={{ margin: "0" }}
        // set name prop to equivalent to state's property
        name="elem"
        // either use - this.state['elem'] or this.state.elem
        checked={this.state.elem}
        // value = {elem} no need of this
        onChange={this.checked}
      />
      Is checked : {this.state.elem ? "yes" : "no"}
    </div>
  );
}
```

Comment: Hi, Thanks for the help but the problem stays. I can change the checked value and if I console.log inside checked={console.log(this.state.checked)}, it changes but the view doesn't change

Comment: You cannot supply method as value to `checked` property. such as `console.log` method